# Apollo-client graphql localstate management setup

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm sitting for 2 days trying to get my setup right. My target is Next.js with ApolloGraphQl for Database request as well as local state management handling.

My problem is the setup for the local state management. Don't know why i'm unable to correctly get it to work. I hope you can help me out.

I pushed my actual status of the project on github using the following repo:

https://github.com/Maetes/apollo-next-local

UPDATE:

it is fine to query and mutate the state when i just call the cache object itself so all is fine. But when i try to trigger a resolver, nothing happens. I'ts like the Apollo-client does not see the typedefs and resolvers.

Here is my useApollo Hook with Client init:

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache, NormalizedCacheObject } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { resolvers } from './localResolvers';
import { typeDefs } from './localTypeDefs';
import {
  CREATE_USER,
  GET_CURRENT_USER,
  SET_CURRENT_USER,
  ALL_USERS,
} from './localDocuments';

let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> | undefined;

export type ResolverContext = {
  req?: IncomingMessage;
  res?: ServerResponse;
};

function createIsomorphLink(context: ResolverContext = {}) {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const { SchemaLink } = require('apollo-link-schema');
    const { schema } = require('../pages/api/index');
    return new SchemaLink({ schema, context });
  } else {
    const { HttpLink } = require('apollo-link-http');
    return new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    });
  }
}

function createApolloClient(context?: ResolverContext) {
  let cache = new InMemoryCache();
  cache.writeData({
    data: {
      currentUser: {
        __typename: 'CurrentUser',
        email: '',
        nachname: '',
        title: '',
        id: '',
      },
    },
  });

  let client = new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: createIsomorphLink(context),
    cache: cache,
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
  // client.writeData({
  //   data: {
  //     currentUser: {
  //       __typename: 'CurrentUser',
  //       email: '',
  //       nachname: '',
  //       title: '',
  //       id: '',
  //     },
  //   },
  // });
  return client;
}

export function initializeApollo(
  initialState: any = null,
  // Pages with Next.js data fetching methods, like `getStaticProps`, can send
  // a custom context which will be used by `SchemaLink` to server render pages
  context?: ResolverContext
) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient(context);

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
  // get hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState);
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient;
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;

  return _apolloClient;
}

export function useApollo(initialState: any) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState]);
  return store;
}
```

This is my typedef file:

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
  extend type Query {
    getCurrentUser: CurrentUser!
  }

  type CurrentUser {
    email: String!
    nachname: String!
    title: String!
    id: ID!
    __typename: String!
  }

  extend type Mutation {
    setCurrentUser(
      email: String!
      nachname: String!
      title: String!
      id: ID!
    ): CurrentUser!
  }
`;
```

this are my resolvers:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { GET_CURRENT_USER } from './localDocuments';

export const resolvers = {
  CurrentUser: {
    currentUser: (_: {}, { cache }: { cache: InMemoryCache }) => {
      console.log('Resolver Query triggered');
      // const { user }: any = cache.readQuery({
      //   query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
      // });
      const data: any = {};
      data.__typename = 'CurrentUser';
      return data;
    },
    getCurrentUser: (_: {}, { cache }: { cache: InMemoryCache }) => {
      console.log('Resolver Query triggered');
      // const { user }: any = cache.readQuery({
      //   query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
      // });
      const data: any = {};
      data.__typename = 'CurrentUser';
      return data;
    },
  },

  Query: {
    getCurrentUser: (_: {}, { cache }: { cache: InMemoryCache }) => {
      console.log('Resolver Query triggered');
      // const { user }: any = cache.readQuery({
      //   query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
      // });
      const data: any = {};
      data.__typename = 'CurrentUser';
      return data;
    },
    currentUser: (_: {}, { cache }: { cache: InMemoryCache }) => {
      console.log('Resolver Query triggered');
      // const { user }: any = cache.readQuery({
      //   query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
      // });
      const data: any = {};
      data.__typename = 'CurrentUser';
      return data;
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    setCurrentUser: (
      _: {},
      variables: any,
      { cache }: { cache: InMemoryCache }
    ) => {
      const { currentUser }: any = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_CURRENT_USER });
      console.log('mutationResolver Triggered');
      console.log(
        'olduser',
        currentUser.email,
        currentUser.nachname,
        currentUser.title
      );

      const newUser = {
        email: variables.email,
        title: variables.title,
        nachname: variables.nachname,
        __typename: 'CurrentUser',
      };

      console.log('newUser', newUser);
      const erg = cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
        data: newUser,
      });
      return newUser;
    },
  },
};
```

And finaly my Document file for individual input. Please note in the GetCurrentUserQuery query when i change "getCurrentUser" to "currentUser" all is working fine cause apollo targets the raw object itself.

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

//Server
export const ALL_USERS = gql`
  query allUsersQuery {
    allUsers {
      title
      nachname
      email
      id
      __typename
    }
  }
`;

//client
export const GET_CURRENT_USER = gql`
  query GetCurrentUserQuery {
    getCurrentUser @client(always: true) {
      email
      nachname
      title
      __typename
    }
  }
`;

//Client
export const SET_CURRENT_USER = gql`
  mutation SetCurrentUserMutation(
    $email: String!
    $nachname: String!
    $title: String!
    $id: String!
  ) {
    setCurrentUser(email: $email, nachname: $nachname, title: $title) @client {
      email
      title
      nachname
      id
      __typename
    }
  }
`;

//Server
export const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation CreateUserMutation(
    $email: String!
    $nachname: String!
    $title: String!
    $password: String!
  ) {
    createUser(
      email: $email
      nachname: $nachname
      title: $title
      password: $password
    ) {
      __typename
      email
      nachname
      title
      password
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: it might be helpful for you https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/nextjs-fullstack-serverless/apollo-client/

Comment: thanks. I looked into it and tried like everything without effort.